# Get current parameter in route - Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I'd like to just receive the current parameter in the Angular router whenever it changes.

Per another SO post, my component will not auto-refresh if the router navigates to another param within the same component, but I'm having trouble getting the parameter when the route is activated (so I can update the view).

The Angular docs have something like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.hero$ = this.route.paramMap
      .switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
        this.service.getHero(params.get('id')));
  }
```

However, this isn't working for me, or at least, it would be nice to have something that isn't abstracted into other methods or services.

Is there a simple straightforward way to subscribe to the current parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way with the new paramMap:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
...
constructor(private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) { 
       this.subscription = this.activeRoute.paramMap
        .subscribe(params => {
            if(params.get('id') !== this.myParam) {
                this.myParam= params.get('id');
                //Do things with new parameter - e.g. reload data
            }
        });
}
```

You can additionally use the `params.getAll` or `params.keys` to get information about what parameters are available.

If the `ActivatedRoute` is not populating any params, you can troubleshoot by subscribing to all router events & seeing where your params are going:

```
this.routeChangeDetection = this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
    console.log(this.activeRoute);
    console.log(this.activeRoute.snapshot);
    console.log(this.activeRoute.snapshot.params);
    console.log(this.activeRoute.snapshot.children);
})
```

This may be useful if your params are getting loaded into a child/related component but not the component looking for the parameter change.

Comment: Would it be difficult to make a quick Plunker of this? The subscription doesn't appear to be firing for me, but I'm still troubleshooting..

Comment: OK almost there - The `params` object doesn't exist in the lambda.. is there a way to extract it from the `events`?

Comment: I'm still having all sorts of trouble - though this was helpful for me to start debugging thanks! For some reason, the snapshot does NOT have the parameter `id`. It seems to be contained in `this.activeRoute.snapshot.children.params` and I have no idea why

Comment: Also, I will try to create a Plunker of this & update answer with it - the Angular docs are surprisingly lacking when it comes to "I just want to do X"

Comment: odd, this worked quite well for me. Since you say the 'id' param is not present, maybe if you do the routing + param addition like so  this.router.navigate([ '/your-route' ], { queryParams: { 'id': id } } ?? Just wondering why param is not present .....

Comment: In my case, it's not a queryParam - it's just a basic input parameter to the component. The navigation code is `this.router.navigate(['route', id]);` , but again, for some reason the parameter never gets populated into the primary ActivatedRoute

Comment: OK, so the activatedRoute parent belongs to the component that owns the navigation. So I moved it over.. almost there..

Comment: I edited your answer, then someone else did an ultra-minor edit - let me know if what I wrote mostly makes sense (I think there was a disconnect between what I wanted & what your answer helped with - this edit bridges the gap)

Comment: Right looks good. To bad it didnt solve your case but glad it helped with 'something' :p cheers!